# How to view the sliced part of preserveAspectRatio xMinYMin slice

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm using

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1920 902" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid slice">
```

so that my SVG would not stretch when i resize my window. The SVG is fully covers my webpage at a maximized window and i want to let the user to view everything on the SVG(even if the user have to scroll to view it). But the problem is when i resize the window it slices the overflow part out and were unable to view it. Is there any way to let the user view the overflow part by scrolling or different kind of approach(other than using `preserveAspectRatio`) to do it?
This is the css code that i'm using:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html,
body,
svg {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#Layer_1 {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: You can do this by changing the viewBox of the svg.

Answer (score 1):

As I've commented you can do this by changing the value of the `viewBox` attribute. Next comes a very simple example where you are using a slider to change the viewBox value:

```js
itr.addEventListener("input", ()=>{
  let val = itr.value;
  theSVG.setAttribute("viewBox",`${val} 0 1920 902`)
})
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<input id="itr" type="range" min="-1000" max="1000" value="0">
<svg id="theSVG" viewBox="0 0 1920 902" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid slice">
<polyline points="-500,50 2500,400 -700,850 -500,50" />  
</svg>
```

Comment: It is a very interesting answer but maybe i wasn't clear enough in my description. Let me update it.